# Localhost storage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-context

So the below code is how I'm trying to get `localStorage` to persist a user's state beyond a page refresh.

This essentially works on the homepage, wherein whenever I refresh I see that the `localStorage` does indeed persist even with a refresh. However, when I rout somewhere by interacting with the webpage and refresh on that page, I lose the `localStorage`

I am passing the user state (whose setter is setUser) through the react useContext function. Would be interested to hear anybody's thoughts. Thank you!

```
import axios from 'axios'
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Router } from  'react-router-dom'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
import Homepage from './components/homepage';
import Login from './components/login'
import MapLeaflet from './components/MapLeaflet'
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Signup from './components/signup';
import ArtistPage from './components/artisthomepage'
import {dbMessages, dbPosts, dbSongs, dbArtists, dbReplies} from './firebase/firebase';

const s = new Spotify();

export const InfoContext = React.createContext();
function App() {

  const [artists, setArtists]=useState("")
  const [messages, setMessages]=useState("")
  const [songs, setSongs]=useState("")
  const [posts, setPosts]=useState("")
  const [replies, setReplies]=useState("")
  const [user, setUser]=useState("")
  const [accesstoken, setAccesToken]=useState("")
  const [refreshtoken, setRefreshToken]=useState("")

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const data = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if(data){
      setUser(JSON.parse(data));
    }

  }, []);





  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <InfoContext.Provider value={{replies, setReplies, artists, setArtists, messages, setMessages, songs, setSongs,posts, setPosts, user, setUser, accesstoken, setAccesToken, refreshtoken, setRefreshToken}}>
        <Route exact path="/signup/:id/:access_token" render={()=><Signup />} />
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=><Login />} />

        <Route exact path="/home/:id/:access_token/:refresh_token"  render = {()=> <Homepage ></Homepage>} />


        <Route exact path="/artist/:artistid"  render = {()=> <ArtistPage ></ArtistPage>} />

        <Route exact path="/map" render={()=><MapLeaflet />} />
      </InfoContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you clean up your code sample a bit? What you've posted is not valid JS.

Comment: We're missing part of your logic here. If you're losing state when you route away from a page, it's likely that you need a function in a `useEffect()` to return the user state to local storage before unmounting. That's just a guess though. Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: Sure - I thought that it would be too long, sorry!

Comment: Updated! So when I refresh /homepage, the localstorage persists, but when I refresh /artist, the localstorage doesn't persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was not checking if user exists before setting it as the user object in localstorage! You also need to add user in the brackets for when the useEffect should run.